# Why are these two constraints causing my LP model to be infeasible in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

My current model in Gurobi is infeasible or unbounded and I broke it down to 2 constraints, which are causing the problem. I have a scheduling Problem. g[i,j] is the binary variable, which indicates the sequence on a certain machine. (g = 1, if i is proceed before j.
 x[i,r] is a binary assignment variable (x= if i is assigned to machine r.)

The Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem (IIS) is showing these three constraints and when I am removing the seconds constraint, the model is working, but all g variables are staying 0, which is not what I want

```
for i in packages: 
        model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i, r] for r in machines) == 1)

for i in packages
        for j in packages:
            if i != j:
                for r in machines:
                    model.addConstr(g[i, j] + g[j, i] >= x[i, r] + x[j, r] - 1) 

    for i in packages:
            for j in packages:
                if i != j:
                    for r in machines:
                    model.addConstr(g[i, j] + g[j, i] <= (x[i, r] + x[j, r]) / 2)
```

I really don't see the problem with these constraints: 
both x are 0:

```
g[i, j] + g[j, i] >= -1 
g[i, j] + g[j, i] <= 0
```

one x = 1 and one x = 0:

```
g[i, j] + g[j, i] >= 0 
g[i, j] + g[j, i] <= 0.5
```

both x = 1:

```
g[i, j] + g[j, i] >= 1 
g[i, j] + g[j, i] <= 1
```

Does anyone know, why this is causing the model to be infeasible? Like I described, I can't find any violations here.

EDIT this is my ilp file:

```
Subject To
 _first_constraint: x_1_NRML-1-1 + x_1_NRML-1-2 + x_1_NRML-1-3 = 1
 _first_constraint: x_2_NRML-1-1 + x_2_NRML-1-2 + x_2_NRML-1-3 = 1
 _first_constraint: x_3_NRML-1-1 + x_3_NRML-1-2 + x_3_NRML-1-3 = 1
 _first_constraint: x_4_NRML-1-1 + x_4_NRML-1-2 + x_4_NRML-1-3 = 1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-1 - x_2_NRML-1-1 + g_1_2 + g_2_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-1 - x_3_NRML-1-1 + g_1_3 + g_3_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-2 - x_3_NRML-1-2 + g_1_3 + g_3_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-2 - x_4_NRML-1-2 + g_1_4 + g_4_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-2 - x_2_NRML-1-2 + g_1_2 + g_2_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-3 - x_2_NRML-1-3 + g_1_2 + g_2_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-2 - x_3_NRML-1-2 + g_2_3 + g_3_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-3 - x_3_NRML-1-3 + g_2_3 + g_3_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-3 - x_4_NRML-1-3 + g_2_4 + g_4_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-3 - x_3_NRML-1-3 + g_1_3 + g_3_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-1 - x_3_NRML-1-1 + g_2_3 + g_3_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-1 - x_4_NRML-1-1 + g_1_4 + g_4_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_1_NRML-1-3 - x_4_NRML-1-3 + g_1_4 + g_4_1 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-1 - x_4_NRML-1-1 + g_2_4 + g_4_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_2_NRML-1-2 - x_4_NRML-1-2 + g_2_4 + g_4_2 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_3_NRML-1-1 - x_4_NRML-1-1 + g_3_4 + g_4_3 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_3_NRML-1-2 - x_4_NRML-1-2 + g_3_4 + g_4_3 >= -1
 seconds_constraint: - x_3_NRML-1-3 - x_4_NRML-1-3 + g_3_4 + g_4_3 >= -1
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-3 - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-3 + g_1_2 + g_2_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-1 - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-1 + g_1_3 + g_3_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-2 - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-2 + g_1_3 + g_3_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-3 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-3 + g_1_4 + g_4_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-1 - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-1 + g_1_2 + g_2_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-1 - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-1 + g_2_3 + g_3_2
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-3 - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-3 + g_2_3 + g_3_2
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-1 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-1 + g_2_4 + g_4_2
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_2_NRML-1-2 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-2 + g_2_4 + g_4_2
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-2 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-2 + g_3_4 + g_4_3
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_1_NRML-1-1 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-1 + g_1_4 + g_4_1
   <= 0
 third_constraint: - 0.5 x_3_NRML-1-3 - 0.5 x_4_NRML-1-3 + g_3_4 + g_4_3
   <= 0
Bounds
Binaries
 x_1_NRML-1-1 x_1_NRML-1-2 x_1_NRML-1-3 x_2_NRML-1-1 x_2_NRML-1-2
 x_2_NRML-1-3 x_3_NRML-1-1 x_3_NRML-1-2 x_3_NRML-1-3 x_4_NRML-1-1
 x_4_NRML-1-2 x_4_NRML-1-3 g_1_2 g_1_3 g_1_4 g_2_1 g_2_3 g_2_4 g_3_1 g_3_2
 g_3_4 g_4_1 g_4_2 g_4_3
End
```

I tried it with a relative small amount. I have packages 1,2,3,4 and machines NRML-1-1, NRML-1-2 and NRML-1-3.

Here is a mcve:

```
from gurobipy import *

model = Model("mcve")

M = 60000
packages = [1, 2, 3, 4]
machines = [1, 2, 3]

h_ = {}
for i in machines:
    h_[i] = 20

print(packages)
print(machines)
print(h_)


x = {}
for i in packages:
    for r in machines:
        x[i, r] = model.addVar(lb=0, obj=0, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x_" + str(i) + "_" + str(r))

g = {}
for i in packages:
    for j in packages:
        g[i, j] = model.addVar(lb=0, obj=0, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="g_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j))

T__ = {}
for i in packages:
    T__[i] = model.addVar(lb=0, obj=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

Ttotal = {}
Ttotal = model.addVar(lb=-1e30, obj=1, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

model.modelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE
model.update()
# Add Constraints

for i in packages:
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i, r] for r in machines) == 1, name=' first constraint')

for i in packages:
    for j in packages:
        if i != j:
            for r in machines:
                model.addConstr(g[i, j] + g[j, i] >= x[i, r] + x[j, r] - 1, name='second constraint')

for i in packages:
    for j in packages:
        if i != j:
            for r in machines:
                model.addConstr(g[i, j] + g[j, i] <= (x[i, r] + x[j, r]) / 2, name = 'third constraint')

for i in packages:
    for j in packages:
        if i != j:
            model.addConstr(T__[i] <= T__[j] - quicksum(x[i, r] * h_[r] for r in machines) + M * (1 - g[i, j]), name='Zusammenhang T__ und g1')
           # model.addConstr(T__[j] <= T__[i] - quicksum(x_[j, r] * h_[r].total_seconds() for r in workstation) + M * g[i, j], name='Zusammenhang T__ und g2')

for i in packages:
    model.addConstr(Ttotal <= T__[i] + quicksum(x[i, r] * h_[r] for r in machines))


model.optimize()
model.computeIIS()
model.write("model.ilp")
```

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically, your small model says

- first_constraint:
  Assign 4 packages to 3 machines (exactly one machine to each package)
- second constraint: If packages i, j are on the same machine g[i, j] + g[j, i] must be 1
- third constraint: If any machine does not have both packages i and j, then g[i, j] and g[j, i] must both be 0.

Together they make it impossible for two packages to be on the same machine, since they would both be on one machine and also both not be on any any of the others.

It looks like for the third constraint, you are intending to say g[i, j] must be 0 unless there exists a machine does have both packages i and j.

Comment: oh thank you David! You are right, with the third constraint, I wanted to say that g[i, j] or g[j, I] can only be 1 if they are assigned to the same machine. But this is not what it says.. If I delete the third constraint, it works! So now I just have to figure out how to implement the correction of it.